# How can I change the default directory IIS uses to a folder on my desktop?

Tags: windows, iis

I am hosting my own website on IIS 7 / Win Server 2008 R2. Everything is working fine, but I want to change the root directory from C:\inetpub\wwwroot to C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyWebsite

I changed this in the IIS Manager by going to DefaultSite->Basic Settings -> Physical Path 
and changing the directory. But now I get a permissions error.

Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

How can I solve this?

Some information I found via googling was this:

In Microsoft Windows Explorer, locate the folder that contains the file that you want to browse.
Right-click the folder, and then click Properties.
Click the Security tab.
**Add the account of the authenticated user.**
Grant the Read permission to the account, and then click OK

The bold is where I get confused. What "User" must I add? Requests are going to be coming through the browser, so won't everybody need to have access? And if so how do I add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add *Read* access for IIS_IUSRS.